# Clonezilla multiple image copies

Tags: clone, clonezilla

I have made an image of my laptop with Clonezilla on an external usb drive.
Can I copy that image on another usb drive in order to have a second image copy?
Or I have to reclone the hard disk on the second usb drive?
In other words, can I simply copy and paste the image to have multiple backup or I lose something (cannot restore the image)?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you check what was written to the external USB drive? If Clonezilla created files on a drive with a normal file system, then you can simply copy all files to a different location. (I don't know if it is possible in Clonezilla to store an image on a raw device.)

Comment: Clonezilla does not like it when you move images. This has been tried and tested in my workplace. I know this is certainly the case with server paths, which all differ, however, if you make sure the two USB's have the exact same folder structure it might just work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It's just a folder of files. Just make sure not to rename the files inside it.